# How to edit an .EPS Book cover in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I just purchased this .EPS blank book cover, I thought I'd get it in .psd format, but I got it as a .EPS format, and I have no idea how to integrate the cover of a book in it.

[image: .EPS Blank Book Cover I purchased]

Comment: Have you tried to open it in Photoshop? It should be able to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I tried opening it in Photoshop, but it just gave me an image, that's all.

Comment: If they told you it was an EPS, you could have known ... there are templates such as this where you can fill in your own image, but they are *Photoshop* templates, because they use special PS functions.

Comment: So it's impossible to integrate my own image in a vector file as this one right? I can only do that if I purchased a Photoshop Mockup?

Comment: "Impossible", well no. But with Illustrator, you need to manually wrestle your art into the bended perspective that this cover needs.

Comment: I know it's too late for you now, but in the future, you don't need to buy these kinds of things.  http://www.psdcovers.com/ has _tons_ of free photoshop actions to create PSDs for just about any product you'd need :)

Comment: @Manly Thank you, I always buy .PSD stuff, I just didn't pay attention to the extension. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the file, you can drop your cover art into it using Illustrator.

We're going to use the front cover shape as a clipping mask for your cover artwork.

[image: Showing cover shape]

Import your artwork and move the layer so it's just above the front cover shape.

[image: Importing artwork]

Duplicate the cover path and place it above the cover art layer.

[image: Cover shape duplicated above art layer]

You'll need to distort your artwork to match the perspective and curve of the cover. If your art is vector, you can use various Illustrator tools until you get it right. My sample has a raster image in it, so I distorted it in Photoshop and re-imported.

[image: cover art distorted to match perspective]

Select your cover art and the duplicate cover shape and Make Clipping Mask (Object > Clipping Mask > Make). Set the clipping group to Multiply so it picks up the shading of the underlying shape. Your art can either extend to the spine area, or you can place separate spine artwork in that same clipping group.

[image]

Comment: I bought a .PSD Mockup, but your answer seems to be making sense and very helpful, so thank you for taking time to explain!

Comment: You can use the same technique in Photoshop—just use the front cover layer as a clipping layer and don't bother duplicating it.